# SQL statement needed

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables Player table, its weapon table and dummy table 'possess weapon'.
player table has player_id,player_name, weapon table has weapon_id, weapon_name, weapon_cost. possesss weapon table has player_id, weapon_id.

player table

```
player_id      player_name
1               mr.A
2               mr.B
```

weapon table

```
weapon_id      weapon_name       weapon_cost
1              sniper            100
2              gun               120
3              hummer            90
```

possess weapon table

```
player_id      weapon_id
1              1
1              2
1              3
2              2
2              3
```

i tried a sql statement for show the player name, total number of weapons that he hold and total costof all weapon he currently held.... but errors are come out like "player name is not as part of an aggreagate function" i used count and sum function. but errors are come out. plz help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you will need to join the tables.  Second, since you are using aggregate functions you will need to use a `GROUP BY` clause on the columns not in an aggregate function.

So your query will be similar to the following:

```
select p.player_name,
  count(w.weapon_id) as TotalWeapons,
  sum(w.weapon_cost) as TotalCost
from ([player] as p
inner join [Possess_Weapon] as pw
  on p.player_id = pw.player_id)
inner join [weapon] as w
  on pw.weapon_id = w.weapon_id
group by p.player_name
```

Note, you will see that MS Access requires parentheses around the joins when there are multiples joins in a query.

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea782/3). The demo is SQL Server but this has been tested in MS Access and it returned the result:

```
| PLAYER_NAME | TOTALWEAPONS | TOTALCOST |
------------------------------------------
|        mr.A |            3 |       310 |
|        mr.B |            2 |       210 |
```

Comment: thz @bluefeet.. i got it :)